# I have two documents which have the SAME EXACT data, yet excel views them DIFFERENTLY? Ruby involved as well

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, excel, csv, sqlite

```
        somefilename = somefilename0
        File.open(somefilename0) do |in_file|
          somefilename = somefilename.sub! '.txt', '.csv'
          File.open(somefilename, 'w') do |out_file|
            in_file.each {|line| out_file << line.gsub('\t', ',') }
          end 
        end
```

I am trying to convert txt to csv and am using ruby. My code works, it converts the txt to csv. I have an original csv file that I converted to the txt file in order to play around with it. So, when I open the original csv file in a notepad text editor, and when I open the converted csv file (which was converted from txt but has the same data) in a notepad text editor, they look EXACTLY the same. There is literally no difference that I can see at all. It's just a small file, a few lines long.

However, when I open these files in excel, for some reason the converted csv file has an extra line between each original line. The original csv file has no such thing. 
When I have them both open in a text editor though, they look EXACTLY THE SAME. What in the world is going on?

EDIT: Also, when I upload the txt file and save it, and convert it to a csv file, and then try to upload that csv file to a database, ruby says Unquoted fields do not allow \r or \n. However, if I just upload the original file to the database, it works just fine.

Comment: I just don't understand, the data looks exactly the same if I edit with notepad, but in excel, there's an extra line between each original line in the newly converted csv file! But in the original csv file, there are no extra lines in excel.

Comment: So there's probably a line-ending issue.

Comment: How do I fix it? Is there anything in my code that I can put to prevent adding any new lines?

Comment: I have also edited the two documents in notepad ++, but now the other document does have the additional lines. So that's weird.

Comment: What editor were you using before? I'm gonna guess notepad, which is notorious for being bad.

Comment: notepad++ is the editor I am using

Comment: Try running dos2unix on the files to get rid of the Windows line endings.